# Is there a difference between the Master Assassin Armour and the armour from the Hagia Sophia

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I got the armour from the Hagia Sophia, when I saw that it covered Ezio's face I went back to see if I could remove just the headgear by selecting a piece of the Master Assassin Armour, I had a feeling that, like the other Ultimate Armour sets in the previous games, by selecting one piece I would equip the entire set.

When I put the Master Assassin Armour back on, I noticed that my health was mainly unchanged, I went back to the armour I got from the Hagia Sophia because I wasn't checking the stats at the time and notice they were the exact same.

I am wondering, is there a difference between the 2 sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stats for both the Master Assassin's armour & Ishak Pasha's armour (which is found from the Hagia Sophia) are identical:

```
Spaulders/Pauldrons: 4 Health, 8 Resistance [Unbreakable]
Chest Guard:         6 Health, 8 Resistance [Unbreakable]
Bracers/Vambraces:   2 Health, 8 Resistance [Unbreakable]
Greaves:             3 Health, 8 Resistance [Unbreakable]
```

It seems that they both have hidden abilities however; 'the armour also had a hidden effect, which was silent sprinting

The only difference which is mentioned is that while wearing Ishak Pasha's armour that the guards are more likely to flee due to a belief that it is cursed.

Source(s):

http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Armor_of_Ishak_Pasha
http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Master_Assassin_Armor